# How to read file in s3 directory only knowing file extension using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a spark workflow which outputs a csv file into its own directory with a randomized filename and a few accessory files which are not `.csv` files. I need to read that file in through a separate python workflow, which if I knew the exact filename I would use:

```
bucket = "bucketName"
file_name = "/user/myName/output/date/dataset/file_name.csv"
s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
obj = s3.read_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name)
```

Since I dont know the exact file name, what I need to do is simply read the only file in that s3 path that has a .csv extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide the **exact** Key to S3 to access the object.

Therefore, you will first need to **list the contents** of the bucket. Here's some code that can prints the name of the first CSV object in a given directory.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,Prefix='folder1/')

objects = [object['Key'] for object in response['Contents'] if object['Key'].endswith('.csv')]

if len(objects) > 0:
    print(objects[0])
```